# Raspberry pi - startup tkinter script issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I made a tkinter script (python3) which work perfectly when I launch it manually from the terminal.

I wanted to start it on launch so I modified the `/etc/profile` with :

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/script/main.py
```

The thing is that the script is launched but I only got a white screen as if my tkinter GUI wasn't working.

Does someone have an explanation ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my crystall ball at home. You should provide your code as [MCVE].

Comment: well my tkinter script works perfectly so the problem is obviously not there...

Comment: @Lafexlos I must be a magician ;)

Comment: Why does it have to be sudo?

Comment: You can bypass sudo if your user has root permission. But if he doesn't and your program must access files with root permission then you must use sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem :

The tkinter script is looking for the ressources (images, etc.) in the folder in which it is executed.

By running `python3 /home/pi/script/main.py` tkinter will look for the ressources in the folder in which we execute from (as default it is the home directory (`~`)).

Tkinter didn't find an image so it stoped on the error (as any python script do)
I just had to change the directory with `cd` as so :

```
cd /home/pi/script
sudo python3 main.py
```